# Why isn't the XSL displaying any data

Tags: xml, xslt, ektron

I  have the following XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template name="displayEventDetails" match="/">
        <div class="serviceHolder brClear">
            <xsl:for-each select="/root/Event">
                <h2 class="defaultHdrColor">
                    <xsl:value-of select="title" />
                </h2>
                <div class="hrHolder">
                    <hr class="hrDivider" />
                </div>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XML:

```
<root>
    <Event>
        <title>Prepared Childbirth Classes </title>
        <speaker>Certified Instructor</speaker>
    </Event>
</root>
```

All it display is in the HTML source is:

```
<div class="serviceHolder brClear"></div>
```

I am calling from my ASP.net page:

```
<CMS:Collection ID="Collection2" runat="server" DynamicParameter="id" DisplayXslt="Workarea\CustomFiles\displayEventDetails.xsl" />
```

How do I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<CMS:Collection ID="Collection2" runat="server" DynamicParameter="id" DisplayXslt="Workarea\CustomFiles\displayEventDetails.xsl" />
```

changed to

```
<CMS:ContentBlock ID="Collection2" runat="server" DynamicParameter="id" DisplayXslt="Workarea\CustomFiles\displayEventDetails.xsl" />
```

Worked.

Reason: I was not trying to read a collection (which holds two or more content blocks) but trying to read each content block separately, one at a time, which is why the XML format was different and showing up blank.

Comment: Better now. In due time, you'll be able to accept it. Meanwhile, why not add an explanation to the solution? What is `CMS:Collection` meant to do?

Comment: @MathiasMüller Awesome feedback. I added some text for the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Java engine to do the transformation or do you want the browser to do it for you?

If Java then you need to show your source code.

If browser then you have to point to the XSLT from the XML file as shown in this tutorial: http://webdesign.about.com/od/xslt/a/xslt-tutorial-6.htm

Comment: I am just calling from my ASP.net page. Updated my question to reflect it.

Comment: @SiKni8 Are you sure you'd like to select this as the correct answer? In my opinion, it does not answer the question. You can always [**self-answer your question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).